# Reading multiple source files from IICS internal server

Tags: iics

In Data Integration task, I have created a mapping to load data from multiple Csv files to Snowflake table. I want to give a file pattern as the file name has the date timestamp in it. When I try to provide file pattern in the Source object, it is throwing the  error like"OBJECT IS INVALID" . Please help me to solve this

When I try to provide file pattern in the Source object, it is throwing the  error like"OBJECT IS INVALID" . Please help me to solve this